# Can not add memeber to telegram channle with telethon

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot, telethon, py-telegram-bot-api

I want to know what is the this Error

```
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.ChatWriteForbiddenError: You can't write in this chat (caused by InviteToChannelRequest)
```

I tried to add members to my channel with telethon and I got this after adding some one
I want to know I got Ban ? Or can someone explain what is the condition of adding member to telegram channel or groups ?

I writ this code

```
from telethon.errors import PeerFloodError, UserPrivacyRestrictedError, 
UserIdInvalidError, UserChannelsTooMuchError
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import InviteToChannelRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerUser

client = TelegramClient('anon', 15890646, '927d43de2718eaafbc0e713cfc8c8c49')

with client:
    users_list = list()
    chats = client.get_participants('Telethon Chat')
    _id = 0
    for i in chats:
        _id += 1
        users_list.append(i)
    print(len(users_list))
    n1 = 0
    for i in users_list:
        user_to_add = InputPeerUser(i.id, i.access_hash)
        print(user_to_add)
        cnl = 'Telethon Chat'
        try:
            client(InviteToChannelRequest(channel=cnl, users=[user_to_add]))
            n1 += 1
        except PeerFloodError:
            print('Getting Flood Error from telegram. Script is stopping now. Please try again after some time.')
            continue
        except UserPrivacyRestrictedError:
            print("The user's privacy settings do not allow you to do this. Skipping.")
            continue
        except UserIdInvalidError:
            print('The User information is Invalid')
            continue
        except UserChannelsTooMuchError:
            print('UserChannelsTooMuchError')

        print(n1)
        print('sleeping ')
        sleep(5)
        if n1 == 20:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have permission to message in chat

also  in

```
chats = client.get_participants('Telethon Chat')
```

mention username or id..
Not the Name of channel
If it is username then seperate with ' _ '(underscores)